# Dynamic query Help?

Tags: apex, customsetting, dynamic-soql

I have created a custom Setting as "ContactSetting" and one field as "Agents_Field_Name"

So my custom setting is like:
Name:FirstName

Agents_Field_Name:FirstName

I am trying to query Contact record using custom setting mapped field

```
public static Map<string, string> MapMappingTable=new map<string,string>();

 String qry ='';

        for(ContactSetting mappingTableRec  : ContactSetting.getAll().values()){
            if (mappingTableRec.Name != null && mappingTableRec.Agents_Field_Name != Null )
            {
                    MapMappingTable.put(mappingTableRec.Name , mappingTableRec.Agents_Field_Name);
                    qry += mappingTableRec.Name + ',';

                    System.debug('@@@@@@'+qry);
                    System.debug('Mapping Table::::'+MapMappingTable);

            }
        }
        qry = 'Select ' + qry + ' from ContactSetting WHERE Id =\'' + newContactIDs + '\' ';
        ContactSetting conObj = Database.query(qry); 
        system.debug('Contact Query ....... ' +conObj);
```

[image]

Edit:
If I am doing like this:

```
List<ContactSetting> settingList = ContactSetting.getAll().values();
        //List<String> fields = new List<String>(Contact.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet());
        String soql = ''
                      + ' select ' + String.join(settingList, ',')                      
                      + ' from ContactSetting'
                      + ' where Id =:newContactIDs';
        for (ContactSetting c : Database.query(soql)) {
             System.debug('@@@@@@@ for contact c is'+c);

        }
```

Comment: You have not stated the problem.

Comment: I am getting error as " [ " is not valid token

Comment: Post the debug results and also add debug for formed query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<ContactSetting> settingList = ContactSetting.getAll().values();

// ...

                      + ' select ' + String.join(settingList, ',')
```

You're trying to serialize the Custom Setting directly. This is going to cause the system to try and serialize the records, resulting in a query string that looks like this:

```
SELECT [CustomSetting (LastModifiedDate: ..., )], [CustomSetting (LastModifiedDate: ..., )] FROM Object
```

This obviously won't work. Instead, loop over the values first:

```
String[] fields = new String[0];
for(ContactSetting setting: ContactSetting.getAll().values()) {
    fields.add(setting.Name);
}

// ...

    String soql = 'select ' + String.join(fields, ',')
                  + ' from ContactSetting'
                  + ' where Id =:newContactIDs';
```

Note: the leading string really isn't necessary. We typically advocate writing code that's as concise as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is a trailing , in the qry string after all the field names.

```
'Select id, firstname, from'
```

Put the names in a list then join the with a comma instead

Answer (score 1):

Code must be written in a way to check and handle all possible error scenarios. There are plenty of gaps where the query will break and throw errors.

Do not re-use variable with different use cases (`qry` hard to manage). A piece of code with all checks would be like:-

```
String query = ' SELECT '; // Every SOQL has select keyword
        String fields ='';

        for(ContactSetting mappingTableRec  : ContactSetting.getAll().values())
        {
            if (mappingTableRec.Name != null && mappingTableRec.Agents_Field_Name != Null )
            {
                    MapMappingTable.put(mappingTableRec.Name , mappingTableRec.Agents_Field_Name);
                    fields += mappingTableRec.Name + ', '; // Collect fields

                    System.debug('@@@@@@'+fields);
                    System.debug('Mapping Table::::'+MapMappingTable);

            }
        }

        // there must be at least a field for query recods
        if(fields != '')
        {
            // There is "," at each iteration. "FROM" statement do not have immediate ","
            fields = fields.removeEnd(', ');

            query += ' '+fields+' from ContactSetting WHERE Id =\'' + newContactIDs + '\' ';
            ContactSetting conObj = Database.query(qry); 
        }
```

I will recommend to make sure `newContactIDs` must have some value correct before running this query. Check for all possible string join issues.